# using outlook 2010 my contacts are not associated with "address book" when using email

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-outlook-2010, contacts

I'm using Outlook 2010 on a new computer and I have successfully migrated "my contacts" data from my old to new compiter but when using "mail" my address book is empty.  I.e., when I click on the TO or CC button, the address book is empty.  However, all my "contacts" can be found in "contacts."  They just are not associated with address book.  can someone tell me how to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Right click your contacts folder, go to properties > address book > tick the "use as address book" box.